# Swipe not being detected on ListView when in a fragment or dialog fragment

Tags: android, listview, swipe

For some reason Swipe is not being detected when swiping on a listView item. I found that this functionality works when in a normal activity but when in a fragment or a dialog fragment the "swipe to delete" functionality does not work, I need this in a fragment so I would like to see if anyone knows how to get this to work in a fragment if possible. I got the code from https://github.com/JohannBlake/ListViewOrderAndSwipe

Here's the implementation in my code:
I have the listView inside of a dialog fragment
UserFavoritesDialogFragment.java

```
public class UserFavoritesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private final String TAG_LOG = "User Favorites";
    private final String TAG_BOTTOM_VIEW = "BottomView";

    private ArrayList<Person> mPersons = new ArrayList<>();
    private PersonAdapter mAdapterPerson;
    private PersonListViewOrder mPersonsListView;
    private ViewGroup mSwipedViewGroup;
    private JBHorizontalSwipe mJBHorizontalSwipe;

    private boolean mRemovePrevDeleted;
    private Person mPrevDeletedPerson;
    Context mContext;

    static UserFavoritesDialogFragment newInstance(Context context) {
        Context mContext = context;
        UserFavoritesDialogFragment f = new UserFavoritesDialogFragment();

        // Supply num input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vdialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_favorites, container, false);
        getDialog().setTitle("User Favorites");

        Log.d("User Favorites Dialog: ", "Horizontal Swipe before: " + mJBHorizontalSwipe);
        // The main activity needs a HorizontalSwipe object to handle swiping listview items.
        mJBHorizontalSwipe = new JBHorizontalSwipe(ijbHorizontalSwipe);
        Log.d("User Favorites Dialog: ", "Horizontal Swipe after: " + mJBHorizontalSwipe);

        // Add some data to the listview.
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Ben", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_ben)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Brad", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_brad)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Bradley", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_bradley)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Bruce", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_bruce)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Chris", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_chris)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Christian", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_christian)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Denzel", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_denzel)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "George", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_george)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Hugh", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_hugh)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Johnny", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_johnny)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Leo", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_leo)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Liam", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_liam)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Matt", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_matt)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Matthew", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_matthew)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Morgan", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_morgan)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Russell", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_russell)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Tom", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_tom)));
        mPersons.add(new Person(getNewId(), "Will", BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_will)));
        Log.d("User Favorites Dialog: ", "Person Array: " + mPersons);
        mPersonsListView = (PersonListViewOrder) vdialog.findViewById(R.id.lvPersons);
        mPersonsListView.setPersonList(mPersons);
        mAdapterPerson = new PersonAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.person_item, mPersons, mJBHorizontalSwipe, mPersonsListView, new IListItemControls() {
            @Override
            public void onUndoClicked(View v) {
                // When the Undo button on a list item is pressed, we need to reset the state of deletion.
                mRemovePrevDeleted = false;
                mPrevDeletedPerson = null;
            }
        });

        mPersonsListView.setAdapter(mAdapterPerson);

        mPersonsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // This is where you put your code to handle the user tapping on a list item, i.e.
                // when the item's top view is being displayed.
                Person person = (Person) view.getTag();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), person.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Handles removing a deleted item if the user scrolls the listview.
        // NOTE: Don't use a ScrollListener on the listview as this will cause bad
        // side effects. Motion events for the listview must be handled by the
        // onTouchEvent method in PersonListViewOrder in order for this kind of listview
        // to function properly.
        mPersonsListView.setVerticalScrollCallback(new PersonListViewOrder.IVerticalScrollCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onVerticalScroll() {
                // This method gets called when the user scrolls the listview vertically.
                if (mPrevDeletedPerson != null) {
                    int pos = mAdapterPerson.getPosition(mPrevDeletedPerson);
                    View vPrevDeleted = mPersonsListView.getChildAt(pos - mPersonsListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                    mAdapterPerson.animateRemoval(vPrevDeleted);
                    mRemovePrevDeleted = false;
                    mPrevDeletedPerson = null;
                }
            }
        });



        return vdialog;
    }

    /**
     * Used to handle callbacks when the user swipes list items.
     */
    private JBHorizontalSwipe.IJBHorizontalSwipe ijbHorizontalSwipe = new JBHorizontalSwipe.IJBHorizontalSwipe() {
        @Override
        public void onReposition(float x, boolean scrollingRight, float scrollDelta) {
            // Currently not used. You can use this callback to do something while the user is swiping a list item.
        }

        @Override
        public void onTopViewVisibilityChange(View vTop, boolean visible) {
            // This callback gets called when the list item's top view changes from fully visible to
            // fully invisible.

            mSwipedViewGroup = (ViewGroup) vTop.getParent();
            final Person person = (Person) mSwipedViewGroup.getTag();
            person.deleted = !visible;
            mRemovePrevDeleted = false;

            // Using setPressed is necessary in various places throughout the app in order
            // to restore the background color of the top view. This is required because list
            // items don't receive the ACTION_UP event which would normally restore the background
            // color. The ACTION_UP is not received because code in PersonListViewOrder as well
            // JBHorizontalSwipe and CustomListItem intercept the motion events and take over
            // control when a ACTION_DOWN is received.

            vTop.setPressed(false);
            mPersonsListView.setPressed(false);

            if ((person == mPrevDeletedPerson) && !person.deleted)
                mPrevDeletedPerson = null;

            if ((person.deleted) && (mPrevDeletedPerson != null) && (person != mPrevDeletedPerson))
                mRemovePrevDeleted = true;

            View vBottom = mSwipedViewGroup.findViewWithTag(TAG_BOTTOM_VIEW);
            PropertyValuesHolder pvhAlphaCurrent;

            ButtonBottomView btnUndo = (ButtonBottomView) vBottom.findViewById(R.id.btnUndo);
            mAdapterPerson.onItemSwiped(person, btnUndo);

            // If the top view is swiped out of view, we want to animate the bottom view's
            // visibility to gradually show, which is done by changing its alpha.

            if (person.deleted)
                pvhAlphaCurrent = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("alpha", 0, 1);
            else
                pvhAlphaCurrent = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("alpha", 1, 0);

            ObjectAnimator animatorView = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(vBottom, pvhAlphaCurrent);
            animatorView.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            animatorView.setDuration(300);

            animatorView.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    // If a previous item has been deleted but is still visible, we
                    // need to remove it from the list using some animation.

                    if (mRemovePrevDeleted) {
                        int pos = mAdapterPerson.getPosition(mPrevDeletedPerson);

                        if ((pos >= mPersonsListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()) && (pos <= mPersonsListView.getLastVisiblePosition())) {
                            View vPrevDeleted = mPersonsListView.getChildAt(pos - mPersonsListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                            mAdapterPerson.animateRemoval(vPrevDeleted);
                        } else {
                            mAdapterPerson.remove(mPrevDeletedPerson);
                        }
                    }

                    if (person.deleted)
                        mPrevDeletedPerson = person;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                }
            });

            animatorView.start();
        }
    };


    /**
     * Used to intercept touch events. THIS LOOKS LIKE IT NEEDS TO BE CALLED TO HANDLE THE SWIPE BUT ITS NEVER CALLED. WHY IS THIS?
     */
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        Log.d("User Favorites Dialog: ", "Touch event dispatch called ");
        if (mJBHorizontalSwipe != null)
            mJBHorizontalSwipe.onRootDispatchTouchEventListener(ev);

        return super.getActivity().dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }


    /**
     * Generates a unique ID.
     *
     * @return Returns a random number.
     */
    private long getNewId() {
        Random r = new Random();
        return r.nextLong();
    }

    interface IListItemControls {
        /**
         * A callback that gets called when the user taps on the Undo button.
         *
         * @param v The view that represents the Undo button.
         */
        void onUndoClicked(View v);
    }
}
```

JBHorizontalSwipe.java

```
public class JBHorizontalSwipe {
    private final String LOG_TAG = "JBHorizontalSwipe";
    private final String TAG_TOP_VIEW = "TopView";

    private boolean mFingerUp;
    private float mScrollDeltaX;
    private float mScrollDeltaY;
    private float mMotionEventPrevX;
    private float mMotionEventPrevY;
    private boolean mScrollingRight;
    private View mScrollerView;
    private IJBHorizontalSwipe mIJBHorizontalSwipe;
    private ObjectAnimator mAnimatorView;
    private boolean mAnimating;
    private boolean mCancelAnimation;
    private float mInitialLeft;
    private boolean mTopViewChanged;
    private boolean mTopViewVisible;

    public final static int ANIMATE_POSITION_LEFT_VISIBLE = 0;
    public final static int ANIMATE_POSITION_LEFT_INVISIBLE = 1;
    public final static int ANIMATE_POSITION_RIGHT_VISIBLE = 2;
    public final static int ANIMATE_POSITION_RIGHT_INVISIBLE = 3;

    public JBHorizontalSwipe(IJBHorizontalSwipe ijbHorizontalSwipe) {
        mIJBHorizontalSwipe = ijbHorizontalSwipe;
    }


    /**
     * Receives motion events from the scroller. Scrollers must implement the dispatchTouchEvent method and call this
     * method from there.
     *
     * @param v     Indicates the scroller that sent the motion event.
     * @param event The motion event that was sent.
     */

    public void onScrollerDispatchTouchEventListener(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Log.d("User Favorites Dialog: ", "Touch event connected ");
            mScrollerView = v;
            View vTop = mScrollerView.findViewWithTag(TAG_TOP_VIEW);
            mInitialLeft = vTop.getX();
        }else{
            Log.d("User Favorites Dialog: ", "Touch event disconnected ");
        }
    }

    public void onRootDispatchTouchEventListener(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            // Reposition the top view if necessary.
            mFingerUp = true;

            if (mScrollerView != null) {
                View vTop = mScrollerView.findViewWithTag(TAG_TOP_VIEW);

                if ((vTop != null) && (vTop.getX() != 0))
                    processViewPosition(vTop);

                mScrollerView = null;
            }
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mFingerUp = false;
            mMotionEventPrevX = event.getX();
            mMotionEventPrevY = event.getY();
        }

        if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) && (mScrollerView != null)) {
            // Adjust the position of the view.
            mScrollingRight = event.getX() > mMotionEventPrevX;
            mScrollDeltaX = Math.abs(event.getX() - mMotionEventPrevX);
            mScrollDeltaY = Math.abs(event.getY() - mMotionEventPrevY);
            mMotionEventPrevX = event.getX();
            mMotionEventPrevY = event.getY();

            View vTop = mScrollerView.findViewWithTag(TAG_TOP_VIEW);

            if (((mScrollDeltaX > 10) && (mScrollDeltaY < 10)) || ((vTop != null) && (vTop.getX() != 0))) {
                IJBHorizontalSwipeTouch ijbHorizontalSwipeTouch = (IJBHorizontalSwipeTouch) mScrollerView.getParent();
                ijbHorizontalSwipeTouch.setDisableScrolling(true);

                ListView listview = (ListView) vTop.getParent().getParent();
                listview.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                repositionTopView();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Repositions the top view when the user scrolls it horizontally.
     */
    private void repositionTopView() {
        View vTop = mScrollerView.findViewWithTag(TAG_TOP_VIEW);

        if (mAnimating || mFingerUp)
            return;

        if (mScrollingRight) {
            float x = vTop.getX() + mScrollDeltaX;

            if (vTop.getX() >= (vTop.getWidth() - 1))
                vTop.setX(-(vTop.getWidth() - 1));
            else
                vTop.setX(x);
        } else {
            float x = vTop.getX() - mScrollDeltaX;

            if (vTop.getX() <= -(vTop.getWidth() - 1))
                vTop.setX(vTop.getWidth());
            else
                vTop.setX(x);
        }

        // Change the alpha of the top view as it is being scrolled making it dimmer as it moves off the screen.
        float alpha = (vTop.getWidth() - Math.abs(vTop.getX() - mScrollDeltaX)) / vTop.getWidth();
        vTop.setAlpha(alpha);
    }


    /**
     * This is where the decision is made to either display or hide the view.
     */
    private void processViewPosition(View vTop) {
        if (mFingerUp) {
            if (mScrollerView == null)
                return;

            if (mScrollingRight && (mScrollDeltaX > 50) && (vTop.getX() > 0)) {
                animateView(vTop, ANIMATE_POSITION_RIGHT_INVISIBLE);
                return;
            }

            if (mScrollingRight && (mScrollDeltaX > 50) && (vTop.getX() < 0)) {
                animateView(vTop, ANIMATE_POSITION_RIGHT_VISIBLE);
                return;
            }

            if (!mScrollingRight && (mScrollDeltaX > 50) && (vTop.getX() > 0)) {
                animateView(vTop, ANIMATE_POSITION_LEFT_VISIBLE);
                return;
            }

            if (!mScrollingRight && (mScrollDeltaX > 50) && (vTop.getX() < 0)) {
                animateView(vTop, ANIMATE_POSITION_LEFT_INVISIBLE);
                return;
            }

            // View was moved to the right of its origin.
            if ((mInitialLeft == 0) && (vTop.getX() > 0) && (vTop.getX() < mScrollerView.getWidth() / 3)) {
                animateView(vTop, ANIMATE_POSITION_LEFT_VISIBLE);
                return;
            } else if ((mInitialLeft == 0) && (vTop.getX() >= mScrollerView.getWidth() / 3)) {
                animateView(vTop, ANIMATE_POSITION_RIGHT_INVISIBLE);
                return;
            } else if ((mInitialLeft == 0) && (vTop.getX() > -mScrollerView.getWidth() / 3)) {
                animateView(vTop, ANIMATE_POSITION_RIGHT_VISIBLE);
                return;
            } else if (mInitialLeft == 0) {
                animateView(vTop, ANIMATE_POSITION_LEFT_INVISIBLE);
                return;
            } else if ((mInitialLeft > 0) && (vTop.getX() >= mScrollerView.getWidth() * 2 / 3)) {
                animateView(vTop, ANIMATE_POSITION_RIGHT_INVISIBLE);
                return;
            } else if (mInitialLeft > 0) {
                animateView(vTop, ANIMATE_POSITION_LEFT_VISIBLE);
                return;
            } else if ((mInitialLeft < 0) && (vTop.getX() > -mScrollerView.getWidth() * 2 / 3)) {
                animateView(vTop, ANIMATE_POSITION_RIGHT_VISIBLE);
                return;
            } else {
                animateView(vTop, ANIMATE_POSITION_LEFT_INVISIBLE);
                return;
            }
        } else {
            if (mAnimatorView != null)
                mAnimatorView.cancel();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Makes the top view visible by animating it onto the screen from either
     * the left or right side of the container depending on where its current
     * left position is located.
     *
     * @param vTop The top view to make visible.
     */
    public void showTopView(View vTop) {
        if (vTop.getX() < 0)
            animateView(vTop, ANIMATE_POSITION_RIGHT_VISIBLE);
        else
            animateView(vTop, ANIMATE_POSITION_LEFT_VISIBLE);

        mTopViewVisible = true;
        mTopViewChanged = true;
    }

    /**
     * Shows or hides the top view by animating on to or off of the screen.
     *
     * @param vTop     The top view.
     * @param position Use ANIMATE_POSITION_LEFT_INVISIBLE to slide it off the screen in the left
     *                 direction. Use ANIMATE_POSITION_RIGHT_INVISIBLE to slide it off the screen
     *                 in the right direction. Set it to ANIMATE_POSITION_LEFT_VISIBLE or
     *                 ANIMATE_POSITION_RIGHT_VISIBLE to slide it on to the screen.
     */
    public void animateView(View vTop, int position) {
        if (mAnimatorView != null)
            mAnimatorView.cancel();

        float left;

        switch (position) {
            case ANIMATE_POSITION_LEFT_INVISIBLE:
                left = -vTop.getWidth();
                break;

            case ANIMATE_POSITION_RIGHT_INVISIBLE:
                left = vTop.getWidth();
                break;

            default:
                left = 0;
                break;
        }

        mAnimating = true;
        PropertyValuesHolder pvhXBar = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("x", vTop.getX(), left);
        mAnimatorView = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(vTop, pvhXBar);
        mAnimatorView.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        mAnimatorView.setDuration(200);
        mAnimatorView.addListener(animListener);
        mCancelAnimation = false;
        mAnimatorView.start();

        if ((mIJBHorizontalSwipe != null) && (left != mInitialLeft)) {
            mTopViewChanged = true;
            mTopViewVisible = (position == ANIMATE_POSITION_LEFT_VISIBLE) || (position == ANIMATE_POSITION_RIGHT_VISIBLE);
        } else
            mTopViewChanged = false;

    }


    /**
     * The animation listener. Needed to know when the animation should be canceled.
     */
    private Animator.AnimatorListener animListener = new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            if (mCancelAnimation)
                mAnimatorView.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mAnimating = false;
            mCancelAnimation = false;
            View v = (View) mAnimatorView.getTarget();
            v.setAlpha(1);

            if ((mIJBHorizontalSwipe != null) && mTopViewChanged)
                mIJBHorizontalSwipe.onTopViewVisibilityChange(v, mTopViewVisible);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            mCancelAnimation = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        }
    };


    public interface IJBHorizontalSwipe {
        void onReposition(float x, boolean scrollingRight, float scrollDelta);

        void onTopViewVisibilityChange(View vTop, boolean visible);
    }

    public interface IJBHorizontalSwipeTouch {
        void setDisableScrolling(boolean disable);
    }

    public interface IJBHorizontalSwipeAdapter {
        View getSelectedView();
    }
}
```

user_favorites.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/img">

    <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:rowCount="10"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:background="#313131">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="People"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:id="@+id/textViewPeople2" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/HorizontalLine1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_height="1dip"
            android:background="#aaa"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="2"
            android:layout_row="2"
            tools:context=".UserFavoritesDialogFragment">


            <view
                android:id="@+id/ListViewBackground"
                class="com.example.rapid.rapid.ListViewItemBackground"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp">

                <com.example.rapid.rapid.PersonListViewOrder
                    android:id="@+id/lvPersons"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:divider="#c0c0c0"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                    android:scrollingCache="true"/>

            </view>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Ah! Ok so found out that If I put this into a normal activity it works great, however, if I have this in a dialog fragment OR a fragment which is what I need then the "Swipe to delete" functionality doesn't work, does anyone have an idea on how to get this to work in a fragment or dialog fragment? I will edit my question to better clarify what it is that I need help with.

Comment: Hi! Can you post the xml file for your fragment or dialog fragment.

Comment: Hi! :) , Yes of course! Code was added, please see the changes, if you or anyone else is in need to see more code please let me know and ill be happy to post more! I just hope I don't hit the cap soon for content in my question lol.

Comment: lol huh I guess my situation is really unique? lol no one has any other suggestions or answers :P

Answer (score 0):

Quick look suggests that you probably need to add `android:clickable="true"` in the ScrollView in user_favourite.xml file. What is probably happening is that your clicks or touches are 'leaking' through and not being captured.

Comment: I applied this code to mine and it did not fix my current issue, it does seem like the touches are going through as far as up and down presses from what it looks like in my debug code, but I never can get into the MOVE actions for some reason. It's almost as if the MOVE actions are getting "leaked" through as you say but DOWN and UP presses don't. Very strange.